# Adding menus to multiple pages

Tags: html, css, menu

I have created a menu using cssmenumaker and I received the following;

index.html

script.js

styles.css

I am looking for the simplest way to add these into all my pages. I have over 100 pages so far and I would like to avoid having to put the code from index.html into each page.

Currently have something like this:

head

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css' />
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='menu_jquery.js'></script>
```

body>

ul>

```
    "LOADS OF MENUS"
```

/UL>

Would like to reference the parts from the  and "LOADS OF MENUES" from one location to make it easier to edit them after.

Comment: Are you developing site php based or html based.?

Comment: html, just developing an intranet site to make all our company info more easily accessible.

Comment: i have added answer below check it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different way to do this..

**For pure PHP**

```
< ?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<br/>
Your content
<br/>
< ?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**for HTML PHP**

Let change your `index.html` to `header.php` after that you have to add below code in your every pages. all about you need either local server or hosting server

```
< ?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<br/>
Your content here
<br/>
< ?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**For pure HTML without PHP**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<br/>
Your content here
<br/>
<div id="footer"></div>
<script>
$("#header").load("header.html");
$("#footer").load("footer.html");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: loading a whole framework just for one method is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an intranet site, i suppose the seo is not a problem, so you can keep the menu only in that one html file and include it using xhr:

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  document.write(xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.open("GET", 'menu.html', true);
xhr.send();
</script>
```

Including this on evey page where you want the menu to be.

Comment: I have done this, just copied and paste the code above into the position within the <body> where I want the menu. I did a save as on the html containing the code and called it menu.html. It's in the same folder as the page. The menu is not appearing on the page. Should I be putting something in the <head>

Comment: menu.html should containt only the html of the menu (the <ul> part), also you will need to include the .css in the head and the .js after the code above. Also be sure that the classes, ids and dom tree used by the generated css and js is present in your own html if needed. If it still not show up take a look in the network tab of the browsers and look at the xhr to see if that one is ok.